# Deserialize user, Serialize user not being called, passportjs express

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am using passportjs to manage logins, it looks like serialize and deserialize functions are not being called.

```
var express = require('express'),
    config = require('./config/conf'),
    app = express(),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    session = require('cookie-session'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    passport = require('./config/passport'),
    auth = require('./config/auth'),
    userAuth = require('./userAuth'),
    appSetup = require('./appSetup'),
    port = 3001,
    api = require('./api'),
    admin = require('./admin');

// Connect to mongodb
var connect = function () {
    var options = {server: {socketOptions: {keepAlive: 1}}};
    mongoose.connect(config.dbAddress, options);
};
connect();
appSetup();

mongoose.connection.on('error', console.log);
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', connect);

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); 

app.use(session({
    keys: ['dfhdjf376gdhjgssjgsdfjdfgjdf', 'dkjjksdsdsdsd1d22sdsjksd', 'kjksdj665656kddfdffjkdf5skdj']
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/auth', userAuth(passport));
app.use('/api', auth.api, api);
app.use('/admin', auth.admin, admin);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('listening on ' + port);
});
```

Passport config file

```
var passport        = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local');
var User            = require('../models/user');

// used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('in ser');
    done(null, user._id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log('in deser');
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user) {
        if(err) return done(err);

        if(!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Could not find a user with that username or email'});
        }

        if(user.validPassword(password)) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect Password' });
        }
    });
}));

module.exports = passport;
```

Comment: Can't see the serialization code, is it there?

Comment: @BenDiamant in config/passport added the code then

Comment: any answers to this question? I have the same problem

Answer (score 3):

Comparing your code with examples at [passportjs.org](http://passportjs.org), I see that you use

```
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
```

whereas they use:

```
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
```

Have a look at their example at http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/